# Can you find the memory allocated to an object (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management

I'm facing a memory leak, and while looking for the problem, wondered if there was some way in Node.js to find the memory allocated to a JavaScript Object.  Node provides a way to find the overall heap and stack space, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation or online to find the space for a specific object.

Given the way variables work, it shouldn't be hard to write something within node to find the size, but I was wondering if something, maybe a JavaScript function, already exists to do it?

Comment: There's some kind of memory management plugin for node.js. Maybe in the v8 toolchain

Comment: Chips. I think I pressed the wrong button. This did not deserve down-vote, but upvote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [Node-Profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) you could use to take 2 heap snapshot and search for large objects by comparing their values.

Comment: Node.js has actually no built-in function, but Node-Profiler uses the profiling options of V8 - the engine node.js is built on, so it's some kind of "built-in"

Comment: For people who find this in 2015 and after: Node-Profile is now obsolete.